# Is there a way to cross-compile tensorflow-2 for nvidia jetson boards (AGX, TX2)

Tags: tensorflow, cross-compiling, tensorflow2.0, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

I found a guide for compiling tensorflow-1.5 with CUDA support for TX1, https://jany.st/post/2018-02-05-cross-compiling-tensorflow-for-jetson-tx1-with-bazel.html

Is there a way to do the same for tf-2? I want to install a fork of tf-2 on my AGX board.

The CROSSTOOL file was deprecated in tf-2 (couldn't find it in thirdparty/gpus/crosstool)